# Handle duplicates in Azure Function with EventHub trigger

Tags: c#, azure-functions, azure-eventhub

I have an Azure Function which has Event Hub binding trigger and it receives batch of EventData. I also have FixedDelayRetry for enabling retry for unhandled exceptions (done on purpose).

If one event fails during processing it inside a batch then the whole batch is getting retry again which obviously create an issue of duplicates

So how can I identify the events which have been successfully processed?

Is there a good pattern to store event sequence number and the status to check it before processing it? and how to retrieve those information as Azure functions are stateless.

Answer (score 0):

> If one event fails during processing it inside a batch then the whole batch is getting retry again which obviously create an issue of duplicates

According to Microsoft Documents, partial success is not possible.

Either all Succeed or all Fail. More about [EventDataBatch Class](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/azure.messaging.eventhubs.producer.eventdatabatch?view=azure-dotnet).

Event hubs is designed for millions of events per second, it's not designed for single message processing.

Its work on batches, they work on whole batch processed and if batch fail then retry the specific batch again.

> So how can I identify the events which have been successfully processed?

You can use `try and catch block`, if catch block throws an exception then add this event in Queue and call another function with Queue trigger to process that failed events.

> Is there a good pattern to store event sequence number

If you need to process multiple events in an order so you need to introduce a  `Partition key`, which will allow you for ordered processing.

Comment: Your idea of sending failed events into another Queue with another function is not bad. I have read that I should introduce a 3rd party storage to store the processed events (e.g. Redis Cache) ... not sure if one idea is better than the second.
Regarding introducing `Partition Key`, I have created only one partition in my Event Hub to ensure ordering, would that be better than Partition Key?